# Validating multiple HTML form fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use javascript to validate multiple fields in a HTML form. I can get it to work for a single input, but I cant seem to get it to validate multiple inputs. Here's my JS that works fine -

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var n = document.forms["myForm"]["Name"].value;
    if (n == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<form name="myForm" action="php/contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

then - 

<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"><br><br></div>
```

But I can't seem to get it to also validate this field -

```
<label>Address:</label> 
<input type="text" name="Address" id="Address"><br><br>
```

Comment: Have you tried repeating that same code but changing `"Name"` to `"Address"`?

Comment: Yep, and it works fine. Just can't do multiple fields at the same time.

Comment: My advice - unless this is an excercise or a throwaway usage, don't re-invent the wheel. There are libraries for this, such as https://www.github.com/ozzyogkush/formation (full disclosure - I wrote this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.forms["myForm"]["Name"].value;
    if (name == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    var address = document.forms["myForm"]["Address"].value;
    if (address == "") {
        alert("Address must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="myForm" action="php/contact.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"><br><br></div>

    <label>Address:</label> 
   <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address"><br><br>

</form>
```

Because you're returning `false`, it will only alert the user of the first incorrect field value. It does this in order for each `if` statement. They must correct that field and try again.

Comment: Yep, I got this right before you posted haha! Still thanks for the correct response!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the existing `if` statement, but change `"Name"` to `"Address"`.

> *Just can't do multiple fields at the same time*

If you're saying you want to display a single error message that lists all of the errors then you need to remove the `alert()` and `return` statements from each individual field's validation, because obviously the function stops processing as soon as it reaches any `return` statement. Instead, build up a list of errors, perhaps something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var messages = [];

    if (document.forms["myForm"]["Name"].value == "") {
        messages.push("Name must be filled out");
    }
    if (document.forms["myForm"]["Address"].value == "") {
        messages.push("Address must be filled out");
    }

    if (messages.length > 0) {
        alert(messages.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you doing the same validation on each field, i.e., checking that they're not empty, then you can use a loop, maybe something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var missingFields = [];

    var fields = document.forms["myForm"].querySelectorAll("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].value == "") {
            missingFields.push(fields[i].name);
        }
    }

    if (missingFields.length > 0) {
        alert("You must enter something in the following fields:\n" + missingFields.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But that's a little long winded for what im trying to do.

Comment: Long-winded? It's four extra lines of code at the end, *minus* one line for the `if` for each field. Or if you use the loop version it is basically the same length as code for two fields but handles any number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the `submit` event and then iterate over all of the textual inputs in your form, you can avoid changing this JS code every time you update your HTML:

```js
var inputs = document.forms["myForm"].querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')

document.forms["myForm"].addEventListener('submit', function validate(event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (!inputs[i].value) {
            alert(inputs[i].name + ' is required!')
            event.preventDefault()
            return
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
    <label for="Name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" required/><br><br>
    <label for="Address">Address:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved it!

This worked -

```
<script>
function validateForm() 

   {
    var n = document.forms["myForm"]["Name"].value;
    if (n == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
    var a = document.forms["myForm"]["Address"].value;
    if (a == "") {
        alert("Address must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
     var c = document.forms["myForm"]["City"].value;
    if (c == "") {
        alert("City must be filled out");
        return false;
    }


}
</script>
```

Comment: Why didn't you just accept Nathan Chapman's answer, which is essentially the same as this? (I also mentioned this technique in the first line of my answer.) It's fine to answer your own question in a general sense, but no need to repeat the same thing as an earlier answer.